# Bootstrap table - Sort Update values

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap table and I have `data-sort-order="desc"` and `data-sort-name="ldv"` in may `<table ...>`, where `ldv` is a data field for one of my `<th>`:

```
<tr>
 <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
 <th data-field="trans">Fl</th>
 <th data-field="ldc" data-sortable ="true"> LD</th>
 <th data-field="ldv" data-sortable ="true">LD G</th>
 <th data-field="ldcc" data-sortable ="true">LD C</th>
 <th data-field="ldcv" data-sortable ="true">LD C</th>
</tr>
```

I can sort the data and it works fine, then I update my data on the server-side by clicking on the "update" link on the HTML page and send it to my client to update the entire column:

HTML:

```
<td class = "resvpt">{{ valpt[count] }}</td>
```

Java Script:

```
$(function() {
  $('#retrieve').bind('click', function() {
    //console.log($SCRIPT_ROOT);
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/scf', function(data) {
      var y = document.getElementsByClassName("resvpt");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i].innerHTML = data.valpt[i];
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

And this works fine as well. However, if I sort the data, the values of that column goes back to the original value. I appreciate if you can help me to find the issue.

Comment: Your function is missing a closing `});` and you have a colon at the end instead of a semi-colon.

Comment: It was a typo, as I mentioned it is working fine.